# how to create a user in linux that user can only use a text editor

Tags: useradd

How to create a user in Linux that user can only use a text editor. And if that user exit from the text editor the system automatically shut down

Comment: This isn't a Linux support (QA) site (SE *Unix & Linux* fills that function; https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) but you could have the login script automatically start an editor, then shutdown, possibly mark an editor as the shell for a user (may limit what editors can be used).. etc  but why ask here?  your question as written would be better suited elsewhere.

Comment: The very fact which that user can use a text editor, means it can write/edit/view some files. You should probably come up with another solution to what you want to do; e.g creating an application or so...

Comment: You cannot. Editors all have "shell escapes" (`:!`), file selection (`../../../etc/passwd`), are subject to attack via signals handled by the parent process.